# variable in if statement not defined(again)

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

This is the code that I am having problems with, it only works when there is a state put in. I need it to work when there is a state put in and when a state and a city are put in.  Really all I need is someone to help me with the variable.

```
import urllib2

num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery',
            'Alaska': 'Juneau',
             'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
            'Arkansas': 'Little Rock',
            'California': 'Sacramento',
            'Colorado': 'Denver',
            'Connecticut': 'Hartford',
            'Delaware': 'Dover',
            'Florida': 'Tallahassee',
            'Georgia': 'Atlanta',
            'Hawaii': 'Honolulu',
            'Idaho': 'Boise',
            'Illinois': 'Springfield',
            'Indiana': 'Indianapolis',
            'Iowa': 'Des Moines',
            'Kansas': 'Topeka',
            'Kentucky': 'Frankfort',
            'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge',
            'Maine': 'Augusta',
            'Maryland': 'Annapolis',
            'Massachusetts': 'Boston',
            'Michigan': 'Lansing',
            'Minnesota': 'St. Paul',
            'Mississippi': 'Jackson',
            'Missouri': 'Jefferson City',
            'Montana': 'Helena',
            'Nebraska': 'Lincoln',
            'Nevada': 'Carson City',
            'New Hampshire': 'Concord',
            'New Jersey': 'Trenton',
            'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe',
            'New York': 'Albany',
            'North Carolina': 'Raleigh',
            'North Dakota': 'Bismark',
            'Ohio': 'Columbus',
            'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
            'Oregon': 'Salem',
            'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg',
            'Rhode Island': 'Providence',
            'South Carolina': 'Columbia',
            'South Dakota': 'Pierre',
            'Tennessee': 'Nashville',
            'Texas': 'Austin',
            'Utah': 'Salt Lake City',
            'Vermont': 'Montpelier',
            'Virgina': 'Richmond',
            'Washington': 'Olympia',
            'West Virgina': 'Charleston',
            'Wisconsin': 'Madison',
            'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}

states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',    'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida',
          'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine',
          'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska',
          'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio',
          'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas',
          'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgina', 'Washington','West Virgina', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']

def make_word(words):
    result = ""
    for i in words:
        result += i
    return result

while 1:
    a = raw_input('Put in a place: ')
    a = a.lower()
    y = a.replace(' ', '%20')
    a = list(a)
    a[0] = a[0].upper()
    a = ''.join(a)
    num = 0
    cap = 0

    for key in capitals:
        if key == a:
            page = urllib2.urlopen('http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup/%s' %    capitals[key]).read()
            cap = capitals[key]
        num += 1
    if a in states:
        f = page.find(cap)
    if f != -1:
        start = page.find('data-center_long="', f) + 18
        end = page.find('"', start)
        start1 = page.find('data-center_lat="', end) + 17
        end1 = page.find('"', start1)
        print '%s Latitude: %s Longitude: %s' % (a, page[start1:end1], page[start:end])
    else:
        for b in states:
            l = len(b) + 1
            f = a.find(b)
            if f != -1:
                f = len(a[f:])
                f = len(a) - f
                f = a[:f]
        page = urllib2.urlopen('http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup/%s' % f).read()
        start = page.find('data-center_long="', f) + 18
        end = page.find('"', start)
        start1 = page.find('data-center_lat="', end) + 17
        end1 = page.find('"', start1)
        print '%s Latitude: %s Longitude: %s' % (a, page[start1:end1], page[start:end])
```

This says the variable is not defined but I need the code to stay like this or else it most likely won't work.  Can someone give me a helpful hint or an answer?

Comment: Please, when asking about an error, include the *full traceback*. Copy and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

`f` variable is declared inside `if a in states`. So, if `a in states` condition evaluates to False, `f` will not be defined.